# Display Language list in mutifield

Tags: aem

I want to display list of languages in dialog "multi field"
I have already tried with

CQ.utils.WCM.getLanguageOptions

Answer (score 4):

`CQ.utils.WCM.getLanguageOptions` would solve the puprose. Use it as the `optionsProvider` for the `selection` widget.

```
{
    "jcr:primaryType": "cq:Widget",
    "name": "./demo",
    "xtype": "multifield",
    "fieldLabel": "Choose Applicable Languages",
    "fieldConfig": {
        "jcr:primaryType": "nt:unstructured",
        "optionsProvider": "CQ.utils.WCM.getLanguageOptions",
        "type": "select",
        "xtype": "selection"
    }
}
```

For more information, check the [CQ.WCM API](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.WCM)